# Capture Variable/Object Name causing the error

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

How can I capture the variable name or object name causing an error in VBA?

Ex

```
Sub test()
    On Error GoTo Handler
    i = 0
    n = 1/i
Handler:
    Select Case variablename
        Case "n"
            'do something................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not being caused by a variable. The error is caused by the line of code that attempts to divide 1 by 0.  The assignment doesn't actually happen.

The best way I've found to diagnose issues when I'm actively developing is to have `Stop` and then `Resume` in the error handler.

```
Public Sub func()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'... some code here ...

    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Stop
    Resume
End Sub
```

The way this works is, when there is an error VBA will break (pause the execution, show the instruction pointer arrow and yellow highlighting) on the `Stop`.  You can step to the `Resume` and then once more to find out which specific line of code is causing the error.

Once you start to understand what errors you are encountering you can build individual If ... Then cases for them to handle each appropriately.  When you are ready to release your code into a production environment (i.e., for other users), you would need to replace the Stop/Resume with an unexpected error handler that either logs it or displays it to the user.

Answer (score 1):

While Blackhawk's answer works fine for a small example, I personally prefer to avoid modifying code to track down errors like that. If I'm working on a lot of files trying to track down a nasty bug, it's entirely possible that I might forget to remove any "special code" like `Stop` statements, etc. after I've finished debugging. If any such code makes it to production, that can be quite embarrassing for me. In addition, it can be annoying having to add this code to many different places in order to figure out where the error is happening in the first place (it's not always as obvious as in your example!).

For these reasons, I prefer to use the facilities provided by the VBA Editor. So:

1. **Open** the **VBA Editor**.
2. Go to **Tools > Options**.
3. Select the **General** tab and click the **Break on All Errors** radio button.
4. Click **OK**.

Now run your code and you'll notice that when it reaches this line:

```
n = 1/i
```

you'll get an error dialog saying what the problem is (*"Run-time error '11': Division by zero"*) and you'll get the option to click the *"Debug"* button on the dialog, which will break execution at the above line and will highlight it in yellow.

Once you're done with your debugging and find the error that had been troubling you, you can go back to the VBA Editor options and revert the "Error Trapping" setting back to the default option ("Break on Unhandled Errors").

This way, you've done no changes to the code that you need to remember to revert before releasing the code and the actual operation to set/unset this behaviour only takes a few clicks.